# Trouble Following Proof of Heine-Borel Thorem using Nested Closed Intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I am using the 2nd edition of S. Abbott's *Understanding Analysis.* The Heine-Borel theorem is laid out like so.

> **Theorem 3.3.8 (Heine–Borel Theorem)**. Let K be a subset of R. All of
> the following statements are equivalent in the sense that any one of them implies
> the two others: **(i)** K is compact. **(ii)** K is closed and bounded. **(iii)** Every open cover for K has a finite subcover.

The textbook defines a set to be compact if for every sequence in the set there exists a subsequence converging to a limit in the set.

In the book, it shows that the statements (i) and (ii) are equivalent. The book also walks through a proof that (iii) implies (ii) (and therefore (i)). The book leaves as an excercise to prove that (ii) implies (iii), the final piece in the puzzle of the proof.

I am having trouble with that latter part. It's a bit of a "guided proof". The question which asks for the proof of the Heine-Borel theorem is structured like so:

> **Exercise 3.3.9.** Follow these steps to prove the final implication in Theorem
> 3.3.8.
> Assume K satisfies (i) and (ii), and let $\{O_λ : λ ∈ Λ\}$ be an open cover for
> K. For contradiction, let’s assume that no finite subcover exists. Let $I_0$ be a
> closed interval containing K.

(a) Show that there exists a nested sequence of closed intervals $ I_0 ⊇ I_1 ⊇ I_2 ⊇
\dots $  with the property that, for each $n$, $I_n ∩ K$ cannot be finitely covered, and $\lim|I_n| = 0$ where $|I_n|$ is the length of the interval.

(b) Argue that there exists an $x ∈ K$ such that $x ∈ I_n$ for all $n$.

(c) Because $x ∈ K$, there must exist an open set $O_{\lambda_{0}}$  from the original collection that contains $x$ as an element. Explain how this leads to the desired
contradiction.

I think I'm just sort of lost on how to approach this, and any attempt I've made has pretty much fallen apart. Could anyone be kind enough to give a bit of a hint in the right direction, further than what the questions provide?

Thanks!

Comment: At which step are you lost?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\lim|I_n|=0$"?

Comment: What is your definition of compactness? To me, (iii) is the definition.

Comment: @ArcticChar the book defines compactness as "A set for that all sequences contained within the set have 1+ subsequences that converge to limits inside the set".

Comment: @jasnee I honestly wasn't sure, and was an example of the notation I found confusing. I think it's the size of $I_n$? Like the absolute difference between the upper and lower bounds.

Comment: $|I_n|$ stands for the length of the interval.

Comment: @DownstairsPanda You should edit your question to include the definition of compactness. People do not want to read comments to get all necessary information. And what is a "1+ subsequence"?

Comment: @PaulFrost I think they are saying 'for every sequence in the set there exists a subsequence converging to a limit in the set' so they are using sequential compactness as the starting point.

Comment: @FrancisAdams You are right. But don't you think that this should be properly included in the question?

Comment: You can first prove that there is a countable subcover for $K$ and then assume that for each finite number of sets from the countable cover there is an element of $K$ which is not covered by it. This generates a sequence $x_n$ and one of its limit points, say $x$, lies in $K$. Then obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Warning: In modern higher analysis we often examine infinite-dimensional spaces where condition (ii) does not apply. Many students err about this after having first studied finite-dimensional spaces like $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can proceed: $K$ is contained in $I_0$. Split $I_0$ into two halves. If the part of $K$ in both halves can be covered by finitely many open sets, then all of $K$ can be covered by combining these finitely many open sets. So, one of the halves must *not* be able to be covered by finitely many. Call that one $I_1$. (If neither can be covered, either will do, or you can decide to always take the left one.) Note that the length of $I_1$ is 1/2$|I_0|$.

Continuing to repeat this process, splitting the interval and picking the one where its intersection with $K$ can't be finitely covered, gives you the sequence of $I_n$, and their lengths must go to 0 since you keep dividing the length by 2 each time.

Then you'll need to use the compactness of $K$ in 2, and for 3 use that the $x$ is covered by some $O_\lambda$, $x$ is in every $I_n$, and the $I_n$ get arbitrarily small.

Comment: More precisely  $x\in O_{\lambda}$ so $(x-r,x+r)\subset O_{\lambda}$ for some $r>0$. Now if $n$ is large enough that $|I_n|<r,$ then $ I_n\subset (x-r,x+r)$ because  $I_n$ is an interval and $x\in I_r$. But then $\{O_{\lambda} \}$ is a finite(!) cover of $K\cap I_n$ (because $K\cap I_n\subset I_n\subset O_{\lambda})$, contrary to the condition on $I_n.$

Answer (score 0):

FYI. Here is the more common (and maybe the original) way to prove that (ii)$\implies$ (iii). The cases $K=\emptyset$ or $\min K=\max K$ are trivial so let's ignore them.

Let $\min K= k_0<k_1=\max K.$

Let $C$ be an open cover of $K$. Let $S\subset (k_0,4+k_1)$ where $r\in S$ iff  [$k_0<r< 4+k_1$ and $[k_0,r]\cap K$ can be covered by finitely many members of $C$]....  The "$4+k_1$" is just some arbitrary value greater than $k_1.$

$(\bullet)$. The goal is to show $k_1\in S.$

(i). There exists $c\in C$ and $r\in (k_0,4+k_1)$ such that $k_0\in [k_0,r]\subset c,$ so $S\ne \emptyset.$

(ii). If $k_0<r''<r\in S$ then $r''\in S.$ Because if $D$ is a finite subset of $C$ and $D$ covers $[k_0,r]\cap K$ then $D$ also covers $[k_0,r'']\cap K.$

(iii). We show that $\sup S>k_1$ by showing that if $k_1\ge r\in S$ then there exists $r'\in S$ with $r'>r$. Suppose $k_1\ge r\in S.$ Then:

Case (a): If $r\in K$: There exists $c\in C$ and $r'\in (r,4+k_1)$ such that $[r,r']\subset c,$ and there also exists a finite $D\subset C$ that  covers $[k_0,r]\cap K$ (because $r\in S$), so $D\cup \{c\}$ is a finite subset of $C$ that covers $[k_0,r']\cap K.$ So $r<r'\in S.$

Case (b): If $r\not\in K$: There exists $r'', r'$ with $k_0<r''<r<r' <4+k_1$ and $(r'',r']\cap K=\emptyset$ because $K$ is closed and $r\not \in K.$ Now $k_0<r''<r\in S$ so $r''\in S$ by (ii). So there exists a finite $D\subset C$ that covers $[k_0,r'']\cap K.$ And $D$ also covers $[k_0,r']\cap K$ because $(r'',r']\cap K=\emptyset.$ So $r<r'\in S.$

(iv). Since $\sup S>k_1$ there exists $t$ with $k_0<k_1<t\in S$ so $k_1\in S$ by (ii).

Comment: One point in favor of the proof the book suggests (at least from the author's perspective) is that it is very similar to the book's proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. So you are able to recycle and re-enforce any intuition from that theorem and proof.

Comment: @FrancisAdams . Interesting point.